# MySQL - Why doesn't this query use an index (according to explain)

Tags: mysql, indexing

I was playing with EXPLAIN and ran it on this simple query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM actions WHERE user_id = 17;
```

And was quite suprised to see this output:

```
select_type    SIMPLE
table          actions
type           ALL
possible_keys  user_id
key            null
key_len        null
ref            null
rows           6
extra          Using where
```

My understanding is this means that no index is being used in the look up, is that correct? (There are only 6 rows total in the table at this time, but there will be many more)

The table definition is (inpart):

```
CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Why wouldn't this be using the key value on user_id?

Comment: The fact that index is not used now doesn't mean that it will not be used in the future.

Comment: Probably quicker just to scan the 6 rows in this case. What if you add in another couple of hundred rows?

Comment: @Karolis that doesn't make much sense -- a query on the primary key uses that index even with 6 rows.

Comment: @Will How many rows have user_id = 17 ?

Comment: @Will with only 6 rows the optimiser will normally pick a full scan. In this case it'll almost definitely be quicker as you're selecting * from the table, which means if you use the index you then have to re-access the table to pick up the remainder of the data. If you change your query to `SELECT user_id FROM actions WHERE user_id = 17;` **it's possible** that it may use the index as it doesn't have to look at the table at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. This is when it would require fewer seeks than reading the table directly. It seems that with 6 rows you're in this situation.

Remember to periodically run [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) and [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/analyze-table.html) when you'll have a more realistic data set.

If you think that you can do a better job than the optimizer, you can use the [Index Hint Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: Note: analyze table is not needed for InnoDB tables.