# Is this the proper use of a MySQL index? Why it seems that is not working?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a PHP website that shows in a specific page a list of all comments related to that specific url.

### My query

I do a SELECT query and I get some results. I wanted to add an index in order to make the query quicker:

```
SELECT
commentID, comment, users.userID
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN users
ON comments.userID = users.userID
WHERE contentID = ?
```

**Original query in spanish:**

```
SELECT
comentarioID, comentario, usuarios.userID
FROM comentarios
LEFT JOIN usuarios
ON comentarios.userID = usuarios.userID
WHERE contenidoID = ?
```

### My indexes

As you can see is an easy query, but MySQL needs to search between the +14.000 comments in order to show them, so I added an index:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD INDEX(userID);
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX(userID);
```

So here is how comments indexes look **without** the index:
[image]

### The result

And here is after I added it:
[image]

In both cases (before and after adding the indexes), if I use EXPLAIN for the SELECT query that I've shown at the beginning, I get:
[image]

The tables are all InnoDB.

**Why there is no real difference?**
The speed of the query is almost the same before and after adding the index: (Query took around 0.0163 seconds in both cases).

### Is this post duplicated?

Before declaring this is a duplicated issue, please, note that I've already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655933/mysql-created-index-isnt-showing-up-as-possible-key), and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729001/mysql-why-doesnt-this-query-use-an-index-according-to-explain), and [this other one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/explain-output-suggests-that-my-index-is-not-being-used)... but I didn't find the replies there useful, because my case *in my opinion* is different.

Comment: How many rows are there in the tables?

Comment: total row count?

Comment: Why do you use left join? Do u really have instances of comments with no users? If u do just a join, should be faster.

Comment: add  contenidoID to the index whichever Table it belongs to

Comment: 15.484 comments in total. About the left join instead of join, I do have comments for non registered users, but those get assigned to anon user, so I'll try using just JOIN. And I'll add an index to contenido table for contenidoID.

Comment: Please add complete SHOW CREATE TABLE output for both tables.

Comment: *I wanted to add an index in order to make the query quicker* What time do you want to achieve?

Comment: I can't advise on indexing without knowing which table `contentID` is in.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I *presume* that the ambiguous attributes in your query are from the comentarios table - you should have qualified these)

Because you are using a LEFT JOIN then the DBMS will always find matching rows in comentarios first before it goes looking for data in usuarios. An index is fast way to find rows. So by the time it has found those matching rows, it has no reason to use the new index.

OTOH if you specified a predicate in the users table, it would have used your new userID index index to find the matching rows in the comments table:

```
SELECT
comentarioID, comentario, usuarios.userID
FROM comentarios
INNER JOIN usuarios
ON comentarios.userID = usuarios.userID
WHERE usuarios.name = ?
```

I would expect "UserID" to be unique / the primary key, hence adding a second index on the same attribute is redundant.

Further, if my assumption above holds, your query only outputs attributes which exist in the comentarios table, hence unless you allow comments to be created without a matching user, the join is redundant / expensive and the query can be written as just:

```
SELECT
comentarioID, comentario, userID
FROM comentarios
WHERE contenidoID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE contenidoID = ?` needs `INDEX(contenidoID)`

`WHERE usuarios.name = ?` needs `INDEX(name)`